# Make custom list command in terminal

Tags: 18.04, gnome-terminal

Is it possible to make a list of applications in terminal so if you enter "games" in terminal it would print a list like:

yetris

pacman4console

Comment: By produce you mean prints out?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I meant.

Comment: Added a note - do you mean static, or return a list of actual applications under a category?

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for an alias, or a Shell Script. Perform the following in your `bashrc` file to add as an alias (assuming, you're using bash):

Open your `.bashrc` file with your editor:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

Add the following line:

```
alias games="echo 'list' 'of' 'games'"
```

You can also alias this to run a script, if you find this easier to manage:

```
aliass games="sh /path/to/script"
```

You would then simply have the script `echo` the words in question.